# Initiate execution of a js file from another computer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, browser

Suppose there is a `file1.php` (includes client code) running on an Android smartphone that performs several ajax calls to different remote php servers. The `file1.php` can run locally on smartphone. But, I need to be able to initiate execution of `file1.php` from a PC (using desktop I can easily initiate execution of the file1.php compared to the mobile) so that the file runs on smartphone and just sends a report to the desktop saying task is completed. The calling technology/language does not matter. I only need to initiate execution of `file1.php` from desktop so the code runs locally on smartphone.

Doing such task is a little bit strange; so, I explain. I am trying to read and record instantaneous energy consumption of 1000 tasks running on a mobile device. Thus, I need to have direct interaction to the screen so I can read energy values with less distraction. If I can use a desktop machine to initiate execution of the task on smartphone, I have the screen in my control; task execution is initiated from the desktop and energy values are shown on smartphone screen.

I try to simply use the `http:smartphone ip address:8080/file1.php` in desktop browser and it works very well. But, the problem is that client side tasks are executed inside the desktop browser which is not what I need. I want every client code runs on smartphone and every data transmission takes place between smartphone and the php servers.

I hope it is not confusing. Sorry to bother you and thanks for your quick answers.

Comment: You should use websocket connections to a central server that tells smartphone clients to do things, or write a native mobile app and use push notifications.

Comment: Node.js and Socket.IO are a good fit for this.  You can use them along side your existing PHP if needed.

Comment: great tips. Thanks dudes. I will work on it, but eagerly look for other answers.

Comment: is Ratchet useful PhP websocket here? Is overhead of websocket high considering that connection remains open till one closes it? The computing and networking overhead is crucial for me and I should avoid any thing that drains my battery.